# How to return content of main table in JOIN?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have `table1` and `table2` my goal is execute a query that take all data available (matching the code), this is my query actually:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
         INNER JOIN table2
         ON table1.code = table2.code
```

All working good, but if for example in the `table2` a specific code isn't exists the data of the `table1` aren't returned. An example:

**TABLE1**

```
|CODE|Info|
|R789|Home|
|R788|Away|
```

**TABLE2**

```
|CODE|DESCRIPTION|
|R789| Test
```

will return only the content of `R789`, but I want that also the content of `R788` must be returned, of course only the field of `table1` 'cause in `table2` the record doesn't exists. How can I do that?

Comment: use `left join` instead of `inner join`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `LEFT JOIN`, which will return content from both tables if the "CODE" exists in both, and items from Table1 with `NULL`s for items from Table2 if the code doesn't exist there.

Lots of documentation out there for this. Here's [one example](http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/joins.php) and [another one](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all the data from both tables but matching if corresponds, you should use a full outer join:

```
select a.*,
       b.*
from   table1 a
full   outer join
       table2 b
on     a.code=b.code
```

It will returns something like this:

```
|CODE|Info|CODE|DESCRIPTION|
|R789|Home|R789|Test|
|R788|Away|null|null|
```

Regards